# A proper use of perfect forwarding in C++?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I wonder if the following is a proper use of perfect forwarding in C++ (explanation below):

```
class A
{
  public:

  //...
  template <typename T> A( T&& b,const C& c ) : _b{ std::forward<T>( b ) },_c{ c } { }
  //...

  private:

  B _b;
  C _c;
};
```

An object of type `A` contains a `B` and a `C` object. It is required that an `A` object can be constructed from a pair (`B b`,`C c`) alone. Now the context dictates that it will always be the case that `c` has to be *copied* into `_c` for such a construction. Therefore, `c` is passed as `const C&`. On the other hand, depending on the case, `b` has to be copied into `_b`, or it may be possible to move `b` it into `_b`. Will the above code accomplish this correctly, i.e. will it generate appropriate constructors depending on the way objects of type `A` are constructed in the code? I.e., is this a proper use of perfect forwarding?

I think it does the right thing, but the reason why I'm irritated: I think this is somewhat ugly as I only want to call the constructor with lvalues or rvalues of type `B` in the first argument. The above code would - in principle - allow any type `T`. Is the alternative of defining the two methods

```
A( B& b,const C& c ) : _b{ b },_c{ c } { }
A( B&& b,const C& c ) : _b{ std::move( b ) },_c{ c } { }
```

to be preferred?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If you don't like it, define two constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that `B` can be constructed from as one argument will work in your sample code.

And that isn't a bad thing.

If `B` has a constructor that takes an `int`, you can pass an `int` as the first parameter.  Instead of creating a temporary `B` then moving it into your structure, it will instead directly construct the `B` in your structure from the `int`.

If you really, really want what you are describing, you can enforce it with three means:

```
// copy:
A( B const& b,const C& c ) : _b{ b },_c{ c } { }
// move:
A( B&& b,const C& c ) : _b{ std::move( b ) },_c{ c } { }
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename=std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<
    typename std::decay<T>::type,
    B
  >::value
>::type> A( T&& b,const C& c ) : _b{ std::forward<T>( b ) },_c{ c } { }
```

which blocks any kind of conversion.  Finally, if `B` is cheap to move, you can just do:

```
A( B b, const C& c ): _b(std::move(b)), _c(std::move(c)) {}
```

which follows the idiom "if you want speed, pass by value".

Here implicit conversion from the argument to `B` is blocked as well, unless the caller explicitly converts.